# Writing asynchronous code for Azure's snapshots creation

Tags: python, azure, asynchronous, sdk, python-asyncio

I am new to Azure, Python and Asynchronous programming.

I have a situation where I need to do some heavy tasks (in this case, creating snapshots for Azure's managed disks)

I have something like:

```
def create_snapshot():
    for VM in list_of_virtual_machines:
        snapshot =  compute_client.snapshots.begin_create_or_update(VM.name, VM.location).result() # asynchronous task
        # Do something with the snapshot once it is ready, in the meantime, continue creating other virtual machines' snapshots
```

How do I write code for this situation, and which method should I choose? Threading, Asyncio etc. ? My question might be unclear and vague since I am new to these concepts.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I write code for this situation, and which method should I choose? Threading, Asyncio etc. ?

You can try the following code snippet, taken from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/examples/azure-sdk-samples-managed-disks#create-a-snapshot-of-a-managed-disk-that-is-currently-attached-to-a-virtual-machine):

```
managed_disk = compute_client.disks.get('my_resource_group', 'myDisk')

async_snapshot_creation = self.compute_client.snapshots.begin_create_or_update(
        'my_resource_group',
        'mySnapshot',
        {
            'location': 'westus',
            'creation_data': {
                'create_option': 'Copy',
                'source_uri': managed_disk.id
            }
        }
    )
snapshot = async_snapshot_creation.result()
```

References: [snapshots_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/1486a398c39cf9e2f1b7aa938a3e7e52f55fd6e1/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2022_03_02/aio/operations/_snapshots_operations.py), [Azure Python SDK Compute Client isn't Using Managed Disk Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479744/azure-python-sdk-compute-client-isnt-using-managed-disk-parameters) and [Scale your Python service with Managed Disks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/scale-your-python-service-with-managed-disks/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I am still confused. This snippet creates a snapshot asynchronously,  but how do I make my python code also run this code asynchronously? Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: There is no need to write separate Python code. [`azure-mgmt-compute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines) library takes care of the asynchronous operation. [snapshots_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/1486a398c39cf9e2f1b7aa938a3e7e52f55fd6e1/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2022_03_02/aio/operations/_snapshots_operations.py)